# Redirecting client with NodeJS and Restify

Tags: node.js, restify, passport.js

I'm building a REST backend for an SPA with NodeJS, Restify and PassportJS for authentication. Everything's working except the last step, which is redirecting the client from the backends /login/facebook/callback to the home page of the application.

I've searched online and found lots of answers for ExpressJS but nothing useful for Node-Restify yet. I've managed to pick up a few snippets of code and this is what I'm attempting at the moment:

```
app.get('/api/v1/login/facebook/cb', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: 'email' }), function(req, res) {
    req.session.user = req.user._id;
    res.header('Location', '/#/home');
    res.send();
});
```

The response is sent but the location header is not included and the client is presented with a white screen. How do I do a proper redirect using the Node-Restify API?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Restify's Response interface [now has a `redirect` method](https://github.com/restify/node-restify/blob/958ed9cf974ea2c7b8453a407c624a76c5971725/test/response.test.js#L79).

As of this writing, there's a test showing how to use it [here](https://github.com/restify/node-restify/blob/958ed9cf974ea2c7b8453a407c624a76c5971725/test/response.test.js#L79).

The contents of that test are:

```
server.get('/1', function (req, res, next) {
    res.redirect('https://www.foo.com', next);
});
```

Many folks who use Restify are more familiar with ExpressJS. It's important to understand that (again, as of this writing) one of the three main public API differences affecting porting of Express plugins is that the `res.redirect` method in Restify requires you to pass `next` (or [an InternalError is thrown](https://github.com/restify/node-restify/blob/958ed9cf974ea2c7b8453a407c624a76c5971725/test/response.test.js#L282)). I've personally ported several modules from Express to Restify and the main API differences at first are (in Restify):

- `server.use` is only for path & HTTP-method-agnostic middleware
- `res.redirect` requires that you pass `next`
- Some members or the Request interface are methods rather than values, such as `req.path`. `req.path` is an alias of `req.getPath` in Restify

I am *NOT* saying that under-the-hood they are similar, but that the above three things are the main obstacles to porting over Express plugins. Under-the-hood, Restify has many advantages over Express in my experience using it in both large enterprise applications and personal projects.

Comment: Accepting this as its more in line with intended use of Restify

Comment: For whatever reason, with Restity 4.3.0, I had to include the protocol `https://www.foo.com` otherwise it would just redirect the path only.

Answer (score 11):

You need to use redirection status code 302.

`res.send(302);` or `res.send(302, 'your response');`